# Why the the timestamp function will appear twice in two different cells in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

Hi everyone,

I'm very new to the google apps script. I have a code to print the timestamp in `column S` when the Action show "Transmit", else it will be blank for other type of Action. The timestamp did appear in `Column S` but it appear in `Column O` as well which is not what I want. I attached my code below:

```
function onEdit(e){

  if(e.range.columnStart == 15 && e.range.rowStart >= 12 && e.value == 'Update' || e.value == 'Transmit'){
     e.range.offset(0,2).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  } else {
    e.range.offset(0,2).setValue('')
  }

  if(e.range.columnStart == 13 && e.range.rowStart >= 22 && e.value == 'Transmit'){
     e.range.offset(0,6).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  } else {
    e.range.offset(0,6).setValue('')
  }
}
```

I guess the first `IF` statement print the TimeStamp by `offset(0,2)` and it brings the parameter of `offset()` to the second `IF` statement. I'm not sure how to make the two `IF` statement independent with each other.
Hope to get some advice from you guys. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It works for me

Comment: Sorry Cooper, I realised I paste a wrong code, I already edited my question above, my code have 2 if statements for two action in different cell. I think this is where it goes wrong but not sure how to solve it.

Comment: Your code doesn't agree with your description of what you want.  Please update one or the other.

Comment: Edited my question, please let me know if it is still not clear for you, sorry for the inconvenience cause.

Comment: Well then get ride of that first section because it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: This does what you are describing that you want: `function onEdit(e)
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()=='Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart == 13 && e.range.rowStart >= 22 && e.value == 'Transmit'){
     e.range.offset(0,6).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  } 
}`

Comment: the first section need to be there because it works for another Action in another table. It works well so I didn't mention it in my question. The only thing that doesn't work well is 2nd section

Comment: `function onEdit(e)   if(e.range.getSheet().getName()=='Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart == 13 && e.range.rowStart >= 22 && e.value == 'Transmit'){      e.range.offset(0,6).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");   }  }` This excluded the first section, but first section need to be there, it works well so I didn't mention it in my question

Comment: So what do you want me to change for your clearer understanding?

Comment: From your script and question, I proposed a modified script as an answer by guessing your goal. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the detail information of your goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issue and your goal as follows.

- For example, when the cell "M22" is set to the value of "Transmit", the date is put to the cells "O22" and "S22".
- You want to know the reason of this.
- From your script and question, you might want to achieve the following conditions.

  - When `Transmit` is put to the range of "M22:M", you want to put the date to the column "S" of the same row.
  - When the value except for `Transmit` is put to the range of "M22:M", you want to put the empty value to the column "S" of the same row.
  - When `Update` or `Transmit` is put to the range of "O12:O", you want to put the date to the column "Q" of the same row.
  - When the value except for `Update` and `Transmit` is put to the range of "O12:O", you want to put the empty value to the column "Q" of the same row.

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your script, there are 2 if statements.

  - At 1st if statement, `e.range.columnStart == 15 && e.range.rowStart >= 12 && e.value == 'Update' || e.value == 'Transmit'` is used as the condition. In this case, when "M22" is set to "Transmit", this if statement becomes `true` by `e.value == 'Transmit'`.
  - At 2nd if statement, `e.range.columnStart == 13 && e.range.rowStart >= 22 && e.value == 'Transmit'` is used. In this case, when "M22" is set to "Transmit", this condition becomes `true`.
  - By these situation, `e.range.offset(0,2).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` and `e.range.offset(0,6).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` are run. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.

When my guess, that I showed it above, is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function onEdit(e){
  if (e.range.columnStart == 15 && e.range.rowStart >= 12) {
    if (e.value == 'Update' || e.value == 'Transmit') {
      e.range.offset(0, 2).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    } else {
      e.range.offset(0, 2).setValue('');
    }
  } else if (e.range.columnStart == 13 && e.range.rowStart >= 22) {
    if (e.value == 'Transmit') {
      e.range.offset(0, 6).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    } else {
      e.range.offset(0, 6).setValue('');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tanaike, yes, it works perfectly for me, thank you! I will try to be more specific next time in term of asking question, sorry for the inconvenience cause.

Comment: @weizer Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Btw, I know this is different question, just a short question, is it possible to output the date and time based on New York Time Zone for all the users for this google sheet?

Comment: @weizer Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?